# git push: Missing required Host Header to host GitLab repository

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

When I'm trying to `git push -u origin master` to my repository, I get `400 Bad Request`.
I've purposely redacted some information with < >. **Recently unbundled nginx from gitlab-ee, and have verified accessibility via web browser to gitlab location.**
I've also tried setting the git remote-url to `https://gitlab.<mysite>.com/<user>/project.git` and the same thing happens.

**Error when attempting git push**

`remote: 400 Bad Request: missing required Host header
fatal: unable to access 'https://oauth2:<myawesometoken>.site.com/<user>/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400`

**nginx configuration**

```
upstream gitlab {
    server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
   server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket fail_timeout=0;
   #server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab-workhorse.socketfail_timeout=0;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade_gitlab {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

log_format gitlab_access $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]"$request_method $gitlab_filtere$

map $request_uri $gitlab_temp_request_uri_1 {
  default $request_uri;
  ~(?i)^(?<start>.*)(?<temp>[\?&]private[\-_]token)=[^&]*(?<rest>.*)$"$start$temp=[FILTERED]$rest";
}

map $gitlab_temp_request_uri_1 $gitlab_temp_request_uri_2 {
  default $gitlab_temp_request_uri_1;
  ~(?i)^(?<start>.*)(?<temp>[\?&]authenticity[\-_]token)=[^&]*(?<rest>.*)$"$start$temp=[FILTERED]$$
}
map $gitlab_temp_request_uri_2 $gitlab_filtered_request_uri {
  default $gitlab_temp_request_uri_2;
  ~(?i)^(?<start>.*)(?<temp>[\?&]rss[\-_]token)=[^&]*(?<rest>.*)$"$start$temp=[FILTERED]$rest";
}

map $http_referer $gitlab_filtered_http_referer {
  default $http_referer;
  ~^(?<temp>.*)\? $temp;
}

server {
    server_name gitlab.<mysite>.com www.gitlab.<mysite>.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

    passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;
    passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";
    passenger_user git;
    passenger_group git;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_min_instances 1;


    location @gitlab-workhorse {

        ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
        proxy_read_timeout      3600;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        # Do not buffer Git HTTP responses
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host_with_default;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;

        ## The following settings only work with NGINX 1.7.11 or newer
        #
        ## Pass chunked request bodies to gitlab-workhorse as-is
        # proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
            root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
            gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location / {
            client_max_body_size 0;
            gzip off;
            proxy_read_timeout      300;
            proxy_connect_timeout   300;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade_gitlab;
            proxy_pass http://gitlab;
        }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 422 /422.html;
        error_page 500 /500.html;
        error_page 502 /502.html;
        error_page 503 /503.html;

        location ~ ^/(404|422|500|502|503)\.html$ {
            # Location to the Gitlab's public directory,
            # for Omnibus this would be: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public.
            root /home/git/gitlab/public;
            internal;
        }

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certb$
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.<mysite>.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Cer$
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.gitlab.<mysite>.com gitlab.<mysite>.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    if ($host = www.gitlab.<mysite>.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gitlab.<mysite>.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

**gitlab.rb config**

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.<mysite>.com'
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = [ '<serverIp>/24']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out by looking closer at GitLab documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#vhost-server-block

I overlooked these two settings. This is inside the main server block.

```
# For protocol upgrades from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 we need to provide Host header if its missing
if ($http_host = "") {
    # use one of values defined in server_name
    set $http_host_with_default "git.example.com";
}

if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
}
```

Also, I removed `client_max_body_size` from `location / { ... }` and put it in the parent scope.

Finally, I added `gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = 'https://gitlab.<mysite>.com'` to the `gitlab.rb` config file.

Everything is working now as it should.